# Vaadin 23 upgrade issue with generated-flow-imports

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

I'm in the process of upgrading an application from Vaadin 22 to Vaadin 23.

In development mode, I have some issues (which I'll handle later) but at least I can see the application in the browser without any errors in the javascript console.

However, in production mode (after running clean, vaadinClean and vaadinBuildFrontend gradle targets) the loading indicator shows forever and this javascript error is shown in the console:

```
generated-flow-imports.4b2f7e95.js:12442 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')
    at generated-flow-imports.4b2f7e95.js:12442:262
    at generated-flow-imports.4b2f7e95.js:12442:36
    at generated-flow-imports.4b2f7e95.js:12442:55
    at generated-flow-imports.4b2f7e95.js:12442:195643
```

What could be the cause? How do I even begin diagnosing this issue?

I'm using Vite, Gradle, Spring Boot.

Comment: You did wipe the browser cahe in production I assume? (Or SHIFT+F5)
Perhaps a incompatible addon?

Comment: @AndréSchild yes, I did.